AD auth: How reset the idToken when it expires?
I am working with ReactJs. I am using IdToken for backend api authentication. I am saving it in the localStorage and with every request I am sending it to the backend.
However in an hour the token expires and the backend api calls start failing.
I want to refresh it either by reloading the page or silently. How can I do that?
Here is my code:
This is app.tsx
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from 'App';

import { PublicClientApplication, EventType, EventMessage, AuthenticationResult } from '@azure/msal-browser';

import { msalConfig } from 'auth/authConfig';

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

if (accounts.length > 0) {

    const [{ idToken }] = accounts;

    localStorage.setItem('authStatus', idToken);

    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);

}

msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: EventMessage) => {

    if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload) {

        const payload = event.payload as AuthenticationResult;

        const account = payload.account;

        const { idToken } = account;

        localStorage.setItem('authStatus', idToken);

        msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);

    }

});

export const router = createBrowserRouter([

    {

        path: '/',

        element: <App pca={msalInstance} />,

    },

]);

authConfig.js
import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.AD_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: "https://xxxxxxxx",
    redirectUri: "/",
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (
        level: number,
        message: string,
        containsPii: boolean
      ) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [],
};

export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.xxxxxxx",
};


you can use the acquireTokenSilent method. This allows you to renew the token without requiring user interaction, and you can set up a process to handle this automatically when the token expires.

You cannot refresh ID token, you need to reauthenticate hence make use of acquireTokenSilent method

@Rukmini How can I handle that method?

MSAL refreshes all token automatically for you. Make sure you have granted offline_access scope in your application's azure registration (this scope allows refreshing the token). What is the content of the authConfig?

@Nikolay I updated the question and added the auth file

You do not seem to specify offline_access in your msalConfig. (it is default). You need to specify the offline_access in your azure app registration so that MSAL is able to refresh the token. Open your app registration, go to "API Permission" and add "offline_access" if it is not there. If you do not do that, user will be forced to re-login.

I always suggest like Idris to use aquireTokenSilent().
The msal library checks if the current token is valid (if not it automatically retrieves a new token from Microsoft) and returns it from the storage you selected.
It might fail if the refresh token is expired (e.g. in my case the refresh token expires after 24 hours)
       msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
   .then(response => {
       //use response.accessToken and do your api calls
   })
   .catch(error => {
       // fails if refreshtoken is expired so a new Login is required
       if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
           
         msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest).then(response => {

       });
    }
  });


I am not sure where I have to put this code in react component?

You use this code wherever you want to make an api call. e.g. you somewhere have a api call with fetch and want to add the Bearer Token as a Header you can use aquire token silent to get the access token and and supply it as a Header with response.accessToken

also you could instead of attempting to login you could automatically redirect the user to the index page for a new login (depending on your requirements)

I am saving the token in localstorage so when the screen is Ideal for an hour it expires so want to save it again. Do you have any idea how can I resave in localstorage when it expires?
